# table design for time-dependent data

Tags: sql

I would like to store some time-dependent data on MS SQL Server, for example employee salary history. Attributes include employee number, effective from date, salary, reason of change.

My question is "Should I include the effective to date on the table? " What is the best practice on storing this type of time-dependent data (current effective to = next effective from - 1), i.e. Should I include the value which can be deduce from another record ?

If effective to is to be stored, can I use Trigger to maintain its value?

Michael

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to have is a slowly changing dimension.  The best approach is based on *how* the data wil be used.  After all, if you are never going to query the data, I can save you a bunch of time and perhaps money by advising you not to use a database at all.

That said, I would encourage you to have two dates on each row:

- EffDate
- EndDate

You can then determine the values of any of the values at any given point in history.  This makes querying the data easier.  But, when loading the table, you need to remember to update the `EndDate` of the previously active data.  That is one extra step on the load.

If you only have `EffDate`, then the querying is more difficult, although the load is slightly easier.  If the only thing you will ever do is choose an employee and look at the records in order, this might be sufficient.

As for the nature of the dates.  If the dates are "continuous" (meaning they have a time component), then `EndDate` for one record should be equal to the `EffDate` of the next.  Querying for a time would use:

```
where MYDATE >= EffDate and MYDATE < EndDate
```

If the dates are discrete, then I have the condition that the `EndDate` is one less than the next `EffDate`:

```
where MYDATE >= EffDate and MyDate <= EndDate
```

You could also use `between` for this condition (but be careful when using `between` on anything that looks like a date).

Comment: how about using trigger to maintain the EndDate? Possible?

Comment: @user3638927 . . . Yes, that is totally possible.  Typically when I have used these data structures, the loads are bulk loads, so I do the logic using `merge`/`insert` and `update`.

Comment: Have you create trigger for simple table maintenance (using Update/Insert/Delete sql)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a child table with history of salaries, its primary key is a combined key (employeeId and a sequence id). This table will be your reference for data history. 
ex:
empX, 1, fromDate 10/10/2012, toDate 11/10/2012, 1,980,000$,
empX, 2, .....
empX, 3,....

Your employee table will have the current salary and its effective date. this table will be faster to query from.
..and this employee is a lucky one ;)

Comment: that means end/to date should be keep in the history table.